# Clustering of sparse matrix in python and scipy

Tags: numpy, scipy, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I'm trying to cluster some data with python and scipy but the following code does not work for reason I do not understand:

```
from scipy.sparse import *
matrix = dok_matrix((en,en), int)

for pub in pubs:
    authors = pub.split(";")
    for auth1 in authors:
        for auth2 in authors:
            if auth1 == auth2: continue
            id1 = e2id[auth1]
            id2 = e2id[auth2]
            matrix[id1, id2] += 1

from scipy.cluster.vq import vq, kmeans2, whiten
result = kmeans2(matrix, 30)
print result
```

It says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cluster.py", line 40, in <module>
    result = kmeans2(matrix, 30)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/cluster/vq.py", line 683, in kmeans2
    clusters = init(data, k)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/cluster/vq.py", line 576, in _krandinit
    return init_rankn(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/cluster/vq.py", line 563, in init_rankn
    mu  = np.mean(data, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2374, in mean
    return mean(axis, dtype, out)
TypeError: mean() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)
```

When I'm using kmenas instead of kmenas2 I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cluster.py", line 40, in <module>
    result = kmeans(matrix, 30)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/cluster/vq.py", line 507, in kmeans
    guess = take(obs, randint(0, No, k), 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 103, in take
    return take(indices, axis, out, mode)
TypeError: take() takes at most 3 arguments (5 given)
```

I think I have the problems because I'm using sparse matrices but my matrices are too big to fit the memory otherwise. Is there a way to use standard clustering algorithms from scipy with sparse matrices? Or I have to re-implement them  myself?

I created a new version of my code to work with vector space

```
el = len(experts)
pl = len(pubs)
print el, pl

from scipy.sparse import *
P = dok_matrix((pl, el), int)

p_id = 0
for pub in pubs:
    authors = pub.split(";")
    for auth1 in authors:
        if len(auth1) < 2: continue
        id1 = e2id[auth1]
        P[p_id, id1] = 1

from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, kmeans2, whiten
result = kmeans2(P, 30)
print result
```

But I'm still getting the error:

> TypeError: mean() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

K-means cannot be run on distance matrixes.

It **needs** a vector space to compute means in, that is why it is called k-means. If you want to use a distance matrix, you *need* to look into purely distance based algorithms such as DBSCAN and OPTICS (both on Wikipedia).

Comment: Really, the point I've missed. 

The questions remains how does k-means know that given matrix is a distance matrix? I thought I could load an arbitrary matrix into k-means and get some (may be meaningless) answer.

Comment: I don't know about scipy, but k-means usually expects a classic *data* matrix, not a *distance* matrix. One row per object, one column per dimension.

Comment: I've update code to work with vector space but kmeans still not working. :(

Comment: In your code, P is still a similarity matrix. You will not be able to run k-means with an adjacency matrix. k-means only works with *Euclidean distance*, because the *mean* only minimizes Euclidean distance. Maybe other Minkowski norms too, but **k-means does not converge with arbitrary distances, because the *mean* might not reduce variance for them**.

Comment: So if you want to cluster graphs, then you can not use k-means. It is only for points in Euclidean space. And your co-author graph is not an Euclidean space.

Comment: Thanks, now everything is clear. But why is P similarity matrix though? It is publications x authors no?

Comment: Ok, didn't understand what you meant to do. That indeed would be a vector space, if `p_id` weren't always 0. But it still won't work for k-means, because it's too sparse and binary. You would see means that say something like "is a 0.01% author of publications 1-100" and such artifacts. The mean does not reasonably work for this vector space. At the same time, since it is very high-dimensional, euclidean distance will become meaningless. So since k-means tries to minimize the euclidean distances, which are meaningless, the k-means result will be meaningless. It's really only for low dims.

Comment: DBSCAN and OPTICS may work. As they do not require vectors they are not directly affected by the curse of dimensionality - as long as you can give a useful distance function they will work.
So first you need to understand "similarity" in your domain. DBSCAN needs a threshold on the similarity, when objects are similar enough to cluster. If you set this to "have coauthored an article" and minpts to 2, you will just detect connected subgraphs. You first need to refine your distance function to get more useful results!

Comment: Speaking of subgraph detection. Am I right, that for a given similarity matrix A sum of the form A + (1/2!)*A^2+ (1/3!)*A^3 + ... which is equal to exp(A) will give me subgraphs? In a sense that if i-author and j-author are in the same subgraph then exp(A)(i,j) will be nonzero? I came to this conclusion thinking about random walks on the graph...

Comment: Also, could you point me to the simple subgraph detection algorithms? I will try something simple first and see if results are any good.

Comment: A common technique with RW matrices seems to be to compute the inverse. But you'll have to read up on that yourself, I'm not an expert for that.

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest, "Affinity Propagation" from `scikit-learn`? On the work I've been doing with it, I find that it has generally been able to find the 'naturally' occurring clusters within my data set. The inputs into the algorithm are an affinity matrix, or similarity matrix, of any arbitrary similarity measure.

I don't have a good handle on the kind of data you have on hand, so I can't speak to the exact suitability of this method to your data set, but it may be worth a try, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I will take a look at affinity propagation.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you're looking to cluster graphs, I'd take a look at NetworkX. That might be a useful tool for you. The reason I suggest this is because it looks like the data you're looking to work with networks of authors. Hence, with NetworkX, you can put in an adjacency matrix and find out which authors are clustered together.

For a further elaboration on this, you can see a question that I had asked earlier for inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450521/networkx-finding-the-natural-clusters-of-points-on-a-graph).