# Grouping values in lists from dictionary to create new dictionary with group number for each value using Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, grouping

In the picture below are three groups of touching squares where each individual square is numbered.

[image]

I have been able to use the spatial library ArcPy to construct the dictionary below which uses the square numbers as its keys and a list of numbers for the squares it touches as its values.  For example, square 1 touches only square 4, square 4 touches squares 1 and 6, etc.

```
dict = {1: [4], 2: [3, 5], 3: [2, 5], 4: [1, 6], 5: [2, 3], 6: [4, 8], 7: [9, 10], 8: [6, 11], 9: [7, 10], 10: [7, 9], 11: [8]}
```

From the picture it is clear that there are three groups of touching squares, and so the result I am after is a new dictionary where the keys are the square numbers and the values are the touching group it belongs to.  I'll name the touching groups using letters but these names can be anything so one possible solution would be:

```
newDict = {9:"A",10:"A",7:"A",1:"B",4:"B",6:"B",8:"B",11:"B",5:"C",2:"C",3:"C"}
```

Is there a Pythonic way to go from `dict` to `newDict`?

I am using Python 2.7.14 for my testing.

Comment: This question comes out of my efforts to try and answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/275009/merging-dissolving-all-polygons-adjacent-to-each-other

Comment: You need some kind of recursion to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for your consideration... solution with the Disjoint Set Union By Rank algorithm from CLRS. It's the most efficient disjoint set finding algorithm I know of.

Essentially just view the problem as a disconnected graph, find the parent of each edge using union-find and associate them.

The output associates different set identifiers than uniformly A-Z for each parent, but it's more efficient to generate the mapping of vertices to letters beforehand, instead of associating them after. You can have up to 26 disjoint sets in this way. For any more, you'll probably want to move to numeric identifiers.

Complexity is `O( | d.keys() | * log(| d.values() |) )`

```
d = {1: [4], 2: [3, 5], 3: [2, 5], 4: [1, 6], 5: [2, 3], 6: [4, 8], 7: [9, 10], 8: [6, 11], 9: [7, 10], 10: [7, 9], 11: [8]}


class MSet(object):
    def __init__(self, p):
        self.val = p
        self.p = self
        self.rank = 0

def parent_of(x): # recursively find the parents of x
    if x.p == x:
        return x.val
    else:
        return parent_of(x.p)

def make_set(x):
    return MSet(x)

def find_set(x):
    if x != x.p:
        x.p = find_set(x.p)
    return x.p

def link(x,y):
    if x.rank > y.rank:
        y.p = x
    else:
        x.p = y
        if x.rank == y.rank:
            y.rank += 1

def union(x,y):
    link(find_set(x), find_set(y))

vertices = {k: make_set(k) for k in d.keys()}
edges = []

for k,u in vertices.items():
    for v in d[k]:
        edges.append((u,vertices[v]))

# do disjoint set union find similar to kruskal's algorithm
for u,v in edges:
    if find_set(u) != find_set(v):
        union(u,v)

# resolve the root of each disjoint set
parents = {}

# generate set of parents

set_parents = set() 

for u,v in edges:
    set_parents |= {parent_of(u)}
    set_parents |= {parent_of(v)}

# make a mapping from only parents to A-Z, to allow up to 26 disjoint sets
letters = {k : chr(v) for k,v in zip(set_parents, list(range(65,91)))}

for u,v in edges:
    parents[u.val] = letters[parent_of(u)]
    parents[v.val] = letters[parent_of(v)]

print(parents)
```

Output:

```
rpg711$ python disjoint_set_union_find 
{1: 'C', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'C', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'A', 8: 'C', 9: 'A', 10: 'A', 11: 'C'}
```

I sorted your expected dictionary to make it easier to correlate the set identifiers and check my work:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda k: k[0])
[(1, 'B'), (2, 'C'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'B'), (5, 'C'), (6, 'B'), (7, 'A'), (8, 'B'), (9, 'A'), (10, 'A'), (11, 'B')]
```

In my proposed solution 'B' -> 'C', 'C' -> 'B', 'A' -> 'A', but notice that the set identifier that each vertex belongs in is just a remapping of your expected.

PS: If there exist vertices that do not touch any other vertices (has no edges), the input dict should be generated or modified such that these vertices have an edge to itself.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to provide the correct result, and I'll now try to figure how you got there.

Comment: @PolyGeo this might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: @PolyGeo also, fixed a slight bug, NOW the code will allow for 26 parents, big-o complexity unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort on this.  You can see your solution embedded within mine at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/276565/115 Let me know if you would like more acknowledgement there beyond the link to your answer here.

Answer (score 1):

i tried with recursive solution if you want you can try:

```
dict22 = {1: [4], 2: [3, 5], 3: [2, 5], 4: [1, 6], 5: [2, 3], 6: [4, 8], 7: [9, 10], 8: [6, 11], 9: [7, 10], 10: [7, 9], 11: [8]}



def connected_nodes(dict34):
    final=[]
    for i,j in dict34.items():
        def recursive_approach(dict1, tem, data,check=[], dict_9={}):
            if data!=None:
                dict_9.update({data:dict22[data]})

            dict_9.update({tem: dict1[tem]})


            check.append(tem)
            final.append(dict_9)
            if check.count(tem) > 1:
                return 0

            for i, j in dict1.items():
                if tem in dict1:
                    return recursive_approach(dict1, tem=dict1[tem][-1],data=None)


        recursive_approach(dict22, tem=j[-1],data=i)
    return final


bew=[]
for i in connected_nodes(dict22):
    bew.append(list(i.keys()))


new_bew=bew[:]
final_result=[]
for j,i in enumerate(bew):
    for m in new_bew:

        if set(i).issubset(set(m)) or set(m).issubset(set(i)):
            if len(i)>len(m):
                final_result.append(tuple(i))
                new_bew.remove(m)

            else:
                final_result.append(tuple(m))


        else:
            pass
print(set(final_result))
```

output:

```
{(2, 3, 5), (9, 10, 7), (1, 4, 6, 8, 11)}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort on this which seems to be producing a result that I could massage into exactly what I am after with more time.  For now I have plugged the code from the accepted answer into my larger code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`networkx` library](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/tutorial/tutorial.html) to determine clusters or sub-groups of graphs.

**Given**

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as uppercase

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


%matplotlib inline


d = {
    1: [4], 2: [3, 5], 3: [2, 5], 4: [1, 6], 5: [2, 3], 6: [4, 8], 
    7: [9, 10], 8: [6, 11], 9: [7, 10], 10: [7, 9], 11: [8]
}
```

**Code**

```
G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(d)

# Label sub-groups
sub_graphs = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G))
{val: label for label, sg in zip(uppercase, sub_graphs) for val in sg.nodes()}
# {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'A', 7: 'C', 8: 'A', 9: 'C', 10: 'C', 11: 'A'}
```

---

**Details**

For easier visualization, here are the labeled sub-groups ([see also motivating code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450521/networkx-finding-the-natural-clusters-of-points-on-a-graph)):

```
# Printed subgroups
for label, sg in zip(uppercase, sub_graphs):
    print("Subgraph {}: contains {}".format(label, sg.nodes()))

# Subgraph A: contains [8, 1, 11, 4, 6]
# Subgraph B: contains [2, 3, 5]
# Subgraph C: contains [9, 10, 7]
```

Although I would ultimately recommend a resulting dict of lists for cleaner grouping of data:

```
{label: sg.nodes() for label, sg in zip(uppercase, sub_graphs)}
# {'A': [8, 1, 11, 4, 6], 'B': [2, 3, 5], 'C': [9, 10, 7]}
```

In addition, you can optionally plot these graphs:

```
# Plot graphs in networkx (optional)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort to document this solution.  However, I do not plan to install networkx because I have an undocumented requirement to use only Python libraries that are installed by ArcGIS Desktop (to use with ArcPy).