# Creating unique sets from list of tuples

Tags: python, set

I am trying to create unique clusters of universities that are within 50 miles of each other.

I have a dictionary that has a tuple with the universities' names as the keys and the distance between them as the values:

```
{('University A', 'University B'): 2546,
 ('University A', 'University C'): 2449,
 ('University A', 'University D'): 5,
 ('University A', 'University E'): 1005,
 ('University B', 'University C'): 32,
 ('University B', 'University D'): 132,
 ('University B', 'University E'): 42,
 ('University C', 'University D'): 532,
 ('University C', 'University E'): 1362}
```

I am able to filter these to get the pairs of universities that are within 50 miles of each other:

```
('University A', 'University D')
('University B', 'University C')
('University B', 'University E')
```

How can I iterate through these pairs and create sets of clusters? What I should end up with is a set with Universities A & D and another set with Universities B, C, & E.

There are 100s of universities that I am looking at in reality so the number of pairs is much longer. I am struggling with the creation of new sets within the iteration each time there is a new university cluster.

Comment: So if A, B = 50 and B, C = 45 and A, C = 100, is just a single cluster or 2?

Comment: That should be a single cluster, because B is common to both pairs with a distance of under 50. But if there were to then be a pair D, E that is 35, then that should be made into a brand new cluster that is separate from the cluster with A, B, C. The challenge I'm having is dynamically creating new clusters as we go through all of the different distance pairings.

Comment: I believe this is a graph problem, in particular, connected components. Basically you create a graph where the nodes are the universities and there is and edge between two universities if the distance is below 50. Once you have that graph, find the connected components. THe connected components are the clusters. Do you know what is the output for the example in your post?

Comment: @Daniel was thinking the same - shouldn't be massively hard to do in something using `networkx` either...

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes that's exactly it. The output is being able to name the clusters, which I can use to tag each university in a pandas df, as I'm then trying to add up the number of students within each cluster (using groupby on a new column with the cluster's name). Jon would networkx let me do that tagging? I've used it to create graphs before, but not pulling the names of each cluster out.

Comment: What do you mean by tagging? Give a name to each cluster?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Yes exactly! I've just now created a nx graph and visualize it -- I just want to be able to name each cluster.

Comment: Well you could use the index of the connected component but that is a number

Comment: Based on your graph suggestion I've come across this, which has worked! Thanks very much for your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450521/networkx-finding-the-natural-clusters-of-points-on-a-graph

Comment: @jbachlombardo fantastic - would you mind posting a self-answer then? This kind of thing would be useful for future readers wanting to do the same thing

Comment: What if, for example universities `A, B, C, D` lie on a straight line, each consecutive ones being 50 km apart (`A - - B - - C - - D`). That is `AB = BC = CD = 50`, `AC = BD = 100`, `AD = 150`. Is it one cluster?

Comment: @JonClements done thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete answer, but hope it shows the idea to be tested and optimized.

Filter the keys as a set, then iterate over and use union if any of the pair is in the lookup list, which must be update while iterating. Better to show some code:

```
filtered = ([ set(k) for k,v in u.items() if v <= 50 ])
print(filtered) #=> [{'University A', 'University D'}, {'University B', 'University C'}, {'University B', 'University E'}]

lookup_list = filtered[1]
for pair in filtered:
  if any(e in lookup_list for e in pair):
    lookup_list = lookup_list.union(pair)

print(lookup_list)
#=> {'University B', 'University C', 'University E'}
```

Answer (score 0):

With helpful guidance from @Daniel Mesejo & @Jon Clements and from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450521/networkx-finding-the-natural-clusters-of-points-on-a-graph), I ended up using networkx to solve the problem.

Starting from a list of tuples `clusters`, looking like `[('University A', 'University B'), ('University A', 'University C'), ...]`, I created the graph with:

```
g = nx.Graph()
for c in clusters :
    g.add_edge(*c)
nx.draw(g)
plt.show()
```

[image: Cluster graph]

Then to extract the clusters and give each a unique identifier using a key-value pair in a dictionary where the key is the cluster's number and the values are a list of the nodes (school names) in that cluster:

```
sub_graphs = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(g))
n = len(sub_graphs)
clusters = {}
for i in range(n) :
    clusters[i+1] = list(sub_graphs[i].nodes())
```

And finally to map them back onto the original dataframe:

```
def map_cluster(x) :
    for k, v in clusters.items() :
        if x in v :
            return k

df['Cluster'] = df['School Name'].apply(lambda x: map_cluster(x))
```

I am certain there is a more efficient way to do this and would welcome comments on this approach!

Comment: How is this handling the distance requirement? Isn't this only finding connected components of the graph? I wonder if you should be adding any edges for nodes that are >50

Comment: @HakunaMaData The distances were already filtered, the list `clusters` only contains pairs of schools that were <=50